# Try except stops the service execution

Tags: delphi, try-catch, indy

```
  List := FQueue.LockList;
  for I := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Mail := TIdMessageTaskman(List[I]);
    FEventLogger.LogMessage(  'Mail' + Mail.ToString, EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE , 0, 2);
    try
      try
        FidSmtp.Connect();
        FidSmtp.Send(Mail);
      except
        on e: exception do
        begin
          FEventLogger.LogMessage('Error sending mail  ' + e.ClassName + ', ' +
            e.Message, EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE, 0, 2);
          MarkMailExecution(Mail.TaskID, Mail.NotificationID, False, e.Message);
          Continue;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      begin
      if FidSmtp.Connected then
      FidSmtp.Disconnect;          
      end;
    end;
    FEventLogger.LogMessage(  'after finally', EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE , 0, 2);
    MarkMailExecution(Mail.TaskID, Mail.NotificationID, True, '');
    FreeAndNil(Mail)
```

So the following code works, but as soon as there is a problem sending an e-mail and the exception is raised, the service stops. Is there I way I can make it continue and go through all the Queue? Even if there are messages with errors. For example of an error that stops my service is when "I attach" a file that does not exist.

Comment: Why are you swallowing all exceptions?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan not sure what you mean..

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding

Comment: Becouse there are chances that some of my mails to have problems when sending and I'm trying not to lock the sending of some mails, because 1 or  2 can't be sent.

Comment: Why are you catching **all** exceptions?

Comment: Well, cuz i'm not sure what exception will the e-mail raise and I must bypass any one of them, what do you suggest I would do?

Comment: I suggest you only trap specific error conditions

Comment: First of all, i'm not sure how to do that and second of all, that would block my service at some point. Am I right?

Comment: Never mind. If you'd rather do Pokemon exception handling that's up to you.

Comment: As for your actual question, what debugging have you done?

Comment: It's hard for me to debugg it as it's a Windows Service. What I can say it throws the exception and then goes into finally, but doesn't run the  FEventLogger.LogMessage(  'after finally', EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE , 0, 2); line

Comment: Debugging services is certainly harder. You still need to do it though. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for debugging. If you've not done any debugging then you shouldn't be asking yet.

Comment: I know where the error comes from, i know what how to fix it, that's not my problem. My problem is that i can't know every exception that the Indy can throw, that's my real problem, catching all the exception and bypass them somehow.

Comment: Well, maybe the `finally` block throws the exception. or even the `except` part.

Comment: @kobik it's not the finally block. I've run the procedure without the try finally and it does the same thing.

Comment: @CiucaS The reason you shouldn't trap **all** exceptions is that some  exceptions indicate a bigger problem. E.g. If "out of memory", "access violations", or "general network errors" occur (to name a few), then most likely the rest of your mails would fail as well. As a worst case scenario, your attempts to doggedly insist on trying to send the other mails could corrupt other parts of your app or cause incorrect results/messages/data. You can easily trap specific exceptions: change your handler to: `on E: ESpecifcException do` (you can also have multiple of these in an **except** block).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you've confirmed you get into the **finally** section. So there are 3 possibilities:

1. A line of code in the **finally** section blocks the code from continuing.
2. Another exception is raised in **finally** section.
3. When you enter the **finally** section, you're already in an "exception state". So leaving **finally** takes you to the next finally/except section in the call stack.

You'll have to add debug logging to confirm which, but I suspect number 3. Possible triggers for the existing exception state:

- Your `Mail` instance is not valid, and your swallower caught an Access Violation. When you again try to use `Mail` in the **except** section, you get another Access Violation.
- Something within `MarkMailExecution` triggers its own exception.
- (I'm assuming your logging mechanism isn't failing because you have been getting some information from it.)

Comment: You are right, I've commented everything in except and finally except the Log messages, and the servce doesn't stop. Thank you! I think I can solve it from here.